# Making a nav bar disappear in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm completely new to Xamarin.Forms and C#, and I'm wondering how I can present a stack of Pages within a NavigationPage, without showing the navigation bar. Here's my code so far in App.cs:

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace Test
    {
       public class App
         {
            public static Page GetMainPage ()
              {
                return new NavigationPage (new StartPage ());
              }
         }
    }
```

What can I do to make it so that when `StartPage` is presented, a navigation bar isn't visible on the screen?

Answer (score 36):

In StartPage, add this (in the constructor or ViewAppearing)

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Comment: yes... I added in constructor working for me.. for new users.. ex:        public MainPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            InitializeComponent();
}

Comment: Any idea what this property is for in forms? HasNavigationBarProperty seems to be bindable but does precisely nothing from what I can tell....

Comment: @Jason Do you know why NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); not working on Android?  iOS works correctly.

Comment: you should use `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(<pageName>, false)` @TheDeveloper @UniSize

Answer (score 14):

In `XAML` it can be done as follows, inside `ContentPage` definition

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```